# Can I use Mason's gain formula to find ratio of intermediate node variable to input?

Tags: control-system

In the text book of 'Automatic Control Systems' by Benjamin Kuo, I read like this.

[image: Screenshot]

Consider the following system.
[image]

In some books, I saw they are using Mason's formula to find x2/x1 ? Is that allowed? The above statement from text book says only x3/x1 is allowed to find using Masons formula.

Comment: Your question is too vague, Light Yagami :) I don't know what "case" you're talking about and you mention, "some solve questions". The input and output nodes indicates from start to finish of the flow diagram.

Comment: @ KingDuken I have edited my question.